# How to pass data from the isolate scope to the parent scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am fairly new to using AngularJS, and what I am trying to do is create a directive and call functions from the parent scope within it. I am able to accomplish this, but what I can't seem to figure out is how to pass data from the isolate scope via an expression to the parent scope. The explanation of this in the Angular Developer guide is a little confusing.

The directive:

```js
app.directive('myDir', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-click="parentFunc(someValue)"><div>', 
        scope: {
           parentProp: '=property',
           parentFunc: '&func'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        }
    }
});
```

The markup:

```HTML
<my-dir prop="foo" func="bar(someValue)"></my-dir>
```

The controller:

```js
app.controller('TstCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = 'test';
    $scope.bar = function(value) {
       console.log(value);
    };
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There may be other ways to do this but see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CvzEk/1/) where you would pass in an object to the function using the same parameter names passed into your `func` attribute.

```
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.parentFunc({someValue:'testing'});            
    }
```

So in this case since you called `bar(someValue)` in your `func` attribute you would want to pass in an object with `someValue` in your link function. You're calling `parentFunc` because that's what `&func` is linked to in your isolate scope.